# Delphi 2010 system.pos search utf8string

Tags: delphi

My question is about delphi 2010 system.pos

I would like to understand why :

```
const
ThisStr : UTF8String = 'abcā—46°40’こ';  // — is #$E28094,  ’ is #$E28099

i := Pos('°', ThisStr);   // not found (i = 12 instead of 8)
i := Pos('—', ThisStr);   // i = 0 instead of 5
i := Pos('’', ThisStr);   // i = 0 instead of 11
```

if I convert the char to a string all answers are correct.

```
i := Pos(string('—'), ThisStr) // i = 5
```

NB1 :

```
i := Pos('こ', ThisStr); // i = 12
i := Pos('ā', ThisStr); // i = 4
```

give right answer and don't need to convert from char to string.

NB2 :
sysutils.ansipos, strutils.ansipos, strutils.posex
give the correct answer in all cases, with no need convert char to string.

Comment: Debug this yourself. Find out which overload of `Pos` is used. Find out how the two input strings are encoded.

Comment: 'こ' and 'ā' are implicitly transtyped from UTF8String to string.

But I don't understand why '°', '—' and '’' are not.
Are they already unicodestrings ?
I dont'want them to be rawbytestrings!

if so, why the other two are not ?

For me, the five of them are UTF8Strings.

Comment: This isn't making much sense to me. I'm wondering why you are trying to mix UTF8 and UTF16. Delphi's internal libraries work il with UTF16. Why are you making life hard for yourself. Either switch to UTF16, or find some UTF8 libraries.

Comment: Tks for your help. I agree with you. The reason of this test is because TPerlRegEx for Delphi 2010 works with UTF8Strings and I met the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ThisStr` is a `UTF8String`, and your other `System.Pos()` inputs are untyped literals.  This is an important fact to take note of, because it affects how the compiler calls `System.Pos()`.

In D2010, the `System` unit has has three overloads of `System.Pos()`:

```
function Pos(const substr, str: UnicodeString): Integer; overload;
function Pos(const substr, str: RawByteString): Integer; overload;
function Pos(const substr, str: WideString): Integer; overload;
```

When calling `System.Pos()` without any casting, your inputs match closest to the `RawByteString` overload, as it is the only overload that doesn't require any runtime conversions of your input values.

The compiled character encoding of an untyped literal is based on the context it is used.  The literal `'abcā—46°40’こ'` is being assigned to a `UTF8String`, so it is UTF-8 encoded at compile-time.  A `UTF8String` can be passed as-is to a `RawByteString`, which means your other literals are being assigned to `RawByteString`, and so they will be encoded by the compiler in ANSI, not UTF-8.

Your UTF-8 string has 12 Unicode characters in it.  When encoded in UTF-8, it has 20 `AnsiChar` elements:

```
a = $61
b = $62
c = $63
ā = $C4 $81
— = $E2 $80 $94
4 = $34
6 = $36
° = $C2 $B0
4 = $34
0 = $30
’ = $E2 $80 $99
こ = $E3 $81 $93
```

On the other hand, the character literals will have only 1 `AnsiChar` each when encoded in ANSI (and their values will depend on the default locale of your system, so your results may vary from mine):

```
° = $B0 
— = $97 
’ = $92
こ = $3F (unless your system locale supports this character! mine doesn't)
ā = $61
```

Even if you change the source file encoding to UTF-8, the character literals will still be encoded in ANSI, not UTF-8.

So:

- `Pos('°', ThisStr)` is searching for `$B0`, which is found at element 12
- `Pos('—', ThisStr)` is searching for `$97`, which is not found
- `Pos('’', ThisStr)` is searching for `$92`, which is not found
- `Pos('こ', ThisStr)` is searching for `$3F`, which is not found
- `Pos('ā', ThisStr)` is searching for `$61`, which is found at element 1

The characters being searched for do not match the `UTF8String`, and that is why they are not found as expected.

By casting the 1st parameter of `System.Pos()` to `string`, you are forcing the compiler to use the `UnicodeString` overload instead of the `RawByteString` overload.  As such, the `UTF8String` will be converted to `UnicodeString` at runtime, and the character literals are being assigned to `UnicodeString` so they will be encoded in UTF-16 at compile-time.

The converted `UTF8String`->`UnicodeString` will contain 12 `WideChar` elements:

```
a = $0061
b = $0062
c = $0063
ā = $0101
— = $2014
4 = $0034
6 = $0036
° = $00B0
4 = $0034
0 = $0030
’ = $2019
こ = $3053
```

And your character literals will have 1 `WideChar` each when they are encoded in UTF-16:

```
° = $00B0
— = $2014
’ = $2019
こ = $3053 
ā = $0101
```

So:

- `Pos(string('°'), string(ThisStr))` is searching for `$00B0`, which is found at element 8
- `Pos(string('—'), string(ThisStr))` is searching for `$2014`, which is found at element 5
- `Pos(string('’'), string(ThisStr))` is searching for `$2019`, which is found at element 11
- `Pos(string('こ'), string(ThisStr))` is searching for `$3053`, which is found at element 12
- `Pos(string('ā'), string(ThisStr))` is searching for `$0101`, which is found at element 4

The characters being searched for match the converted `UTF8String`->`UnicodeString` string, and that is why they are found as expected.

`SysUtils.AnsiPos()` and `StrUtils.PosEx()` are not overloaded, they only accept `UnicodeString` as input, so they have the same result as calling the `UnicodeString` overload of `System.Pos()`.  If you include the `AnsiStrings` unit in your `uses` clause, it adds an overload of `AnsiPos()` for `AnsiString`, which will give you very different results than what I described above.

Context and character encodings matter!

Comment: I am very grateful. I got 100% of your so clear and comprehensive explanation (I am not surprised because I read many of your articles).